# Error in vb6 code when running project

Tags: error-handling, vb6

I'm having an error in my project

> Run-time error '13' Type mismatch with this code in vb6

Code:

```
rs.Open "select * from Table1 where ItemName like '%" And txtItemName.Text And "%'", con, adOpenDynamic
```

Can someone help me understand why and how to fix it?

Comment: Please post a larger snippet of code, this error means you are trying to shove data of one type into data of another type - hence the mismatch.

Comment: Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim myListitem As ListItem
lvListItem.ListItems.Clear
rs.Open "select * from Table1 where ItemName like '%" & txtItemName.Text & "%'", db, adOpenDynamic
Do While Not rs.EOF
    Set myListitem = lvListItem.ListItems.Add()
    myListitem.Text = rs!ItemCode
    myListitem.SubItems(1) = rs!ItemName
    myListitem.SubItems(2) = rs!ItemPrice
    myListitem.SubItems(3) = rs!stock
    rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    If txtItemName.Text = "" Then
    lvListItem.ListItems.Clear
    'txtStock.Text = ""
    txtQuan.Text = ""
    txtPrice.Text = ""
    End If

Comment: Now I got this run-time error '3709':
The connection cannot be used to perform this operation. Its either closed or invalid in this context.

and it still leads me to that line of code :(

Comment: Where is your db connection in that code?

Comment: Option Explicit

Public rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Public con As New ADODB.Connection

Sub main()

con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & App.Path & "\ItemDataBase.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"
con.CursorLocation = adUseClient
con.Open
main.Show
ItemRegisterLogin.Show 1

End Sub

Comment: sorry I change the db to con

Comment: the con connection is in a module

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
'%" And txtItemName.Text And "%'
```

with

```
'%" & txtItemName.Text & "%'
```